# Query for products offer in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using

```
productinfo (`productId`, `productName`, `productPrice`, `productSaleprice`, `productImage`, `productLink`, `productColor`, `productSize`, `categoryId`, `sourceProductId`, `sourceId`)
```

where `productinfo` is table, And i display products on the basis of  `productPrice` and `productSaleprice`.

At this moment I fetch all results and calculate everything in PHP like this:

```
$diff=$productPrice-$productSaleprice;
$result=($diff)/($productPrice/100);
```

My question is, is it possible to calculate the same things in MySQl without using PHP?

The result should be displayed in DESC Order

Comment: can you show us what youve tried? then we can help you debug it.

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: first of all I'm telling my table structure, and i want display the product on the percentage base in DESC order, bigger offer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below SQL useful to you.

```
    select `productId`, `productName`, productPrice, productPrice, productPrice-productSaleprice as diff , 
         (productPrice-productSaleprice)/(productPrice/100) as result
    from productinfo
where category= 5
    order by result desc;
```

Thank you

Comment: #Venkatesh Panabaka, It's really good but where is put the 'WHERE' condition for category

Comment: I update my answer can you check it once.